# How do you insert an async return value into a prop before it renders?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I'm not sure if I'm asking the question right. but this is what i'm trying to do, when I'm on the client I make an async request for a csrf token and insert it into headers. How do you insert that value in the header like this? I get undefined value for the token and an error when I use.

> { this.state.session.csrfToken }

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        session: props.session,
    };
}

async componentDidMount() {
    const session = await getSession();
    this.setState({
        session: session
    });
}

render() {
    const props = {
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-Token': { this.state.session.csrfToken }  <-- bad creates error
        }
    }
```

Comment: you're trying to use an asynchronous result synchronously - you can't do that

Comment: not possible before it renders. but in `render`, you can do something like `if(typeof this.state.session.csrfToken !== 'undefined'){/* code... */}else{/* code... */}` to control what to render before/after the async operation.

Comment: That looks like a syntax error (and has nothing to do with asynchrony). Did you mean to use an object literal?

Answer (score 2):

You can't make `componentDidMount` an `async` function. 
At least you can't use it asynchronously and delay render function.

What you should do instead is to have a condition in render function till session is not available.

like this.

```
render() {
    if (!this.state.session || !this.state.session.csrfToken) {
      return <div>waiting for token</div>;
    }

    const props = {
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-Token': { this.state.session.csrfToken }
        }
    }
```

So as setState calls render again - state will have the token and it will render what you wish to render properly.

Comment: Ok great for the solution but i figured you have to take it out of the curly brackets it creates an error.